# Change in length of a right triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, ratio

[image: This is the basic problem]

And so my question is how do I prove the *??*

Comment: This is a whole mess of things. What are you trying to prove exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to write an expression for change in x, with respects to a change in L, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
This can be done through a straightforward application of related-rates to the Pythagorean theorem:
$$ x^2 + a^2 = L^2 $$
$$ \pder{}{x} (x^2 + a^2) = \pder{}{x} L^2 $$
$$ 2x = 2L \pder{L}{x} $$
$$ \pder{L}{x} = \frac{x}{L} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{L^2 - a^2}}{L} = \cos \varphi $$

All of the expressions in the last line are equivalent, use whichever one works best for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just can't seem to see how what is done between row 2 and 3.
Would you mind clarifying? Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you taken calculus yet? If so, this is just a partial derivative. If not, I can write a solution that bypasses calc.

Comment: Thank you that explains it neatly! Your help was much appreciated.